# Last sites and last items in the same list/table/gridview

Tags: list, auditing, gridview

There is a way to put in a list all updates/insert that users to in every list from all the subsites from sharepoint root site(sitecollection)? Also, to add to this list the site info that users create in sitecollection? This list should have information such as: name of item/site - link to the list or site, date on which user create/upload the item or create site, name of the user that did the action. 
Maybe there is some solution without programming.
I saw some posts about this subject.I can use Content Query Web Part, but only for one site not sitecoll. I saw here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa981241.aspx.
I tried with relevant document web part, table content web part, content query web part, but this are only for list or only for sites.
I'm using SP 2010 Enterprise Edition on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly the task is to audit the users activity.

You can use the SharePoint 2010 auditing feature and then publish the report to a library. The SharePoint Server auditing capabilities allow you to track all activities that occur within the environment. The site collection administrator has the ability to set auditing requirements within the environment that determine the types of actions that should be tracked.

To manage audit settings for a site collection, follow these steps:

1. Navigate to the Site Settings page for the top-level site in the site collection.
2. On the Site Settings page, in the Site Collection Administration section, click the Site Collection Audit Settings link.
3. On the Configure Audit Settings page, identify any audit log trimming settings,and select the items to audit:
   a. In the Audit Log Trimming section, identify if automatic audit log trimming should be enabled, identify the number of days of audit log data to retain and specify a location to store audit reporting before trimming the audit log. This is important as you dont want the log files to fill up the space on your drive
   b. In the Documents and Items section, check the boxes in front of the events to audit which you want to track e.g in your case Opening or downloading documents, viewing items in lists, or viewing
   item properties
   c. Once all of the appropriate audit options have been set, click the OK button.

To view the audit reports:

1. Navigate to the Site Settings page for the top-level site in the site collection.
2. On the Site Settings page, in the Site Collection Administration section, click the Audit Log Reports link.
3. On the View Auditing Reports page, click the name of the report you want to execute.
4. For the Run a Custom Report option, the Run a Custom Report Page is presented. On this page, follow these steps:

a. In the File Location section, select where the report should be saved once it is generated.

b. In the Location section, check if the report should be restricted to a specific list, and if so, select the web site where the list is located and select the list.

c. In the Date Range section, specify the optional Start Date and/or End Date to which the report should be restricted.

d. In the Users section, specify which users the report should be restricted to.

e. In the Events section, specify the events the report should be restricted to.In your case include the following events:

• Opening or downloading documents, viewing items in lists, or viewing item properties

• Editing items

Once all of the appropriate report settings have been entered, click the OK button.

1. The report is generated, and the file is saved to the library specified.

Extra: [Auditing in SharePoint 2007](http://www.developer.com/net/net/article.php/3755726/Auditing-in-SharePoint-2007.htm)

**UPD**

Then you need to do this via SP object model, i.e write custom auditing tool which will handle events you need. Look here for example of events http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/08/10/event-receiver-for-sites-in-sharepoint-2010/

Or look at this one http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff400321.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your answer Alex. I did not know much about sharepoint auditing feature. Is really useful for items in lists. But how can I log if an user create a site, or create a list? And put all this logs in one single list? And auditing is for all subsite from a sitecollection? Thank you

Comment: End is not for audit.

Comment: See updated answer